# How to sort on one or more keys on an IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> result set?

Tags: c#, dictionary, json.net, ienumerable

We have a view that makes an ajax call to an API that returns a result set of type `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>` and binds that data to a jQuery DataTable.  Each `Dictionary<string, object>` essentially represents a DataRow.  How can I sort this `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>` collection based on one or more keys and in the order specified on the server-side?

```
var sortOrderables = (JArray)_dtRequest["order"];
for (int i = 0; i < sortOrderables.Count; i++)
{
     var columnIdx = (int)sortOrderables[i]["column"];                
     var columnDir = (string)sortOrderables[i]["dir"];
     var column = (string)_dtRequest.SelectToken(string.Format("columns[{0}].data", columnIdx));    

     foreach(Dictionary<string, object> dataRow in _dataSet)
     {

     }
}
```

Comment: Sorting an individual dictionary is easy, but how would you qualify sorting the collection of dictionaries? What criteria? At best you'd move an entire dictionary above or below another dictionary unless you want to create one mega dictionary that is all of them merged together.

Comment: You're question isn't clear.  `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't have keys.  Secondly, Dictionaries themselves *can not be sorted*.

Comment: Just use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` on the `_dataSet`.

Answer (score -2):

Would this code work?

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            Dictionary<string, DataTable> dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Col A"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.CopyToDataTable());

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DataTable> key in dict.AsEnumerable())
            {
                int numberColumns = key.Value.Columns.Count;
                for (int i = numberColumns - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    key.Value.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x[i]);
                }
            }
```